# LyX justification problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx

I am experiencing some problems with LyX justification. I left all parameters as default, but suddenly when I start a new section the subsequent text automatically changes justification. How can I work this out?

Here are some pictures to let you understand better (the first one is how I want my text to look like, while the second is the incorrect display).

What I want:
[image: correct justification]

What I get:
[image: incorrect justification]

Comment: Strictly this is down to a LyX paragraph `Centre` setting instead of `Paragraph's Default (Left)` Right click text and review your current  paragraph settings (its towards the end of dropdown)

Comment: How did you manage to get the section title centered? I guess you used a wrong way and now everything is centered.